# strcmp doesn't work in my code

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have a problem with **strcmp** in my program.
i'm trying to compare two strings by their length, so i'm using strcmp() for that but when i compare them in my if statement it doesn't work well.

Doesn't strcmp compare length of strings?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[30],b[30],c[30];
    strcpy(a,"computer");
    strcpy(c,"science");
    strcpy(b,a);
    puts(a);
    puts(c);
    puts(b);

    if(strcmp(a,b)==0)
        printf("a=b\n");
    if(strcmp(a,c)<0)
        printf("a<c\n");
    if(strcmp(a,c)>0)
        printf("a>c");

    strcat(a,c);
    puts(a);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `a` is bigger than `c`?

Comment: a cosist of 8 character while c is 7.

Comment: And where in the documentation of `strcmp` does it say that it compares strings based on their length?

Comment: i have read it in a book,i think its wrong.

Comment: @s12b11; Yes. Its completely wrong. Throw that book and take another good one.

Comment: Do you know any good sites for learning c from beginning?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and delete both buffers of fixed size (like `char a[30];`) and functions that write into preallocated buffers (like `strcpy()`) from the list of things that you use. Almost all of their uses will turn into bugs, very likely ones that are a) limiting to your users, and b) that allow malware to take over your process. If you want `strcpy()`, use `strdup()` instead.

Comment: I never understood whats wrong with fixed buffers. Just use e.g. `strncpy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcmp` compares strings *lexicographically* (for strings composed of letters in the same register, it's the same as comparing them alphabetically). Therefore, `"computer"` is less, not greater, then `"science"`, because it is earlier alphabetically.

If you would like compare lengths of the two strings rather than comparing the strings themselves, you should use `strlen`:

```
if(strlen(a) == strlen(b))
   printf("a=b\n");
if(strlen(a) < strlen(c))
   printf("a is shorter than c\n");
if(strlen(a) > strlen(c))
   printf("a is longer than c");
```

Comment: I added your code to mine but it does not print anything.

Comment: @s12b11 That is because a `\n` is missing at the end of the string, in both your code and in mine. When this happens, the output needs to be "flushed" before exiting the program, otherwise you are not going to see the output. Here is a [link to a demo where this problem is fixed](http://ideone.com/bVcmbm).

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares strings based on their [**lexicographic ordering**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which resembles the way words are arranged in a dictionary. By this ordering, string `"science"` is greater than `"computer"`. It is not true that `strcmp` compares string based on their lengths.

`strcmp` consider `str1` less than that of `str2` if either of the following is true;

- The first `i` characters of `str1` and `str2` match, but the `(i+1)`<sup>st</sup> character of `str1` is less than that of `(i+1)`<sup>st</sup> character of `str2`.
  Ex: `abc` is less than that of `abd`.
- All the characters of `str1` match `str2`, but `str1` is shorter (in length) than that of `s2`.
  Ex: `abc` is smaller than `abcd`.

Comment: Do you know any good sites for learning c from beginning?

Comment: If you are a beginner, then before suggesting any sites I would like to suggest you to start from a good book. You can raed [C Primer Plus](http://www.amazon.com/C-Primer-Plus-5th-Edition/dp/0672326965). It is a good book for beginners. But if you want some site then I would suggest you to read [c_FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) and [C Programming Notes](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/top.html).

Comment: I added @dasblinkenlight code to mine but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @s12b11 Here is [a link to an explanation of what's happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045619/using-strcpy-strcmp-strcat-in-c/21045705?noredirect=1#comment31642458_21045705).

Comment: Do you understand what was the root of the problem?